# Trouble Adding New Item to Array

Tags: php, modx

I have an array that I need to add some key/value pairs too but I'm having trouble with it. Here's an example of my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 108
            [pagetitle] => Title
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 35
            [alias] => url-alias
            [menutitle] => 
        )
)
```

I'm trying to insert a new key called "country" along with it's value but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
    foreach($all_items as $item) {

    $country = $modx->getTemplateVarOutput(array("country"), $item['id'], $published=1);
    $item['country'] = $country['country'];
}
```

I've verified that `$country['country']` does contain what I need it to...I just can't seem to add it to the array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass array element by reference if you want to modify it.

```
foreach($all_items as &$item) {
    ...
```

Comment: Why is there a down vote to this, this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the `$item` array is actually only a copy of the the element within `$all_items`.

To achieve what you want you could do it like this:

```
foreach($all_items as &$item) {
   $country = $modx->getTemplateVarOutput(array("country"), $item['id'], $published=1);
   $item['country'] = $country['country'];
}
```

Also see docs for [foreach](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) there you'll find exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are asking:

```
foreach($all_items as $k=>$v) {
    $country = $modx->getTemplateVarOutput(array("country"), $all_items[$k]['id'], $published=1);
    $all_items[$k]['country'] = $country['country'];
}
```